# JUnit FilterRequest not creating filtering out tests

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have created an annotation called Skip to ignore tests with some conditions, as of now I just want to ignore a test if that annotation is present. I have also created a Filter as below.

```
public class SkipFilter extends Filter {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
    if(description.isTest())
        return description.getAnnotation(Skip.class) == null;
    else
        return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String describe() { return "Tests without annotation Skip";    }
}
```

I'm using JUnitCore.run to invoke test on a FilterRequest as shown below.

```
FilterRequest request = new FilterRequest(Request.classes(SimpleTests.class),
                                          new SkipFilter());
new JUnitCore().run(request);
```

SimpleTests.class is a class that has two tests firstTest and secondTest. secondTest has @Skip annotation. However, both the tests are getting executed. Can anyone point me where I'm doing wrong?

I have also tried `request.getRunner().run(new RunNotifier())` and faced the same issue of test not being skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have created the Skip annotation with @Retention as below to be retained by JVM at runtime. This should work.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Skip {
----
}
```

Comment: +1 for catching the error I made earlier, but Nope, I initially didn't put retention policy, after scratching my head for sometime and debugging for some time, I realised that I didn't put it. I posted this question after I have kept retention policy. I debugged and Skip annotation has also come during runtime. Still filter is not working. Any ideas of any other mistakes I might have made?

Comment: I just observed I have two versions of Skip and one doesn't have RetentionPolicy. It is working now. Thanks.